# C# listView Blink/Alternative Color

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, listviewitem

Is it possible to animate `ListView` items in C# ? The purpose is that I have a ListView that is asynchronously modified, and I'd like to animate smoothly the items that have been modified, until the user clicks them. This way items blinking, or whatever would do the trick, are the items that changed which haven't been reviewed yet.

Thank you guys !

UPDATE : sorry, i forgot. Never used WPF before, and I think it's too late to switch to it now. I'm using winforms.

Comment: wpf or winforms? Should be fairly straightforward in wpf using storyboard/doubleanimation and some event handling

Comment: sorry, i forgot. Never used WPF before, and I think it's too late to switch to it now. I'm using winforms.

Comment: Recommendation: Unless it is super-critical, try to avoid outright blinking if you can.  I'd think it was obnoxious.  Simply setting or fading in a color would be nicer IMO.

Comment: that's a point, and that's why I want something light and not too crazy. I prefer a blinker as there might be a few elements in the list sometimes, and the new user who has all elements colored might not perceive it as an update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to do something similar to what you are trying to do but instead of animating the ListView, I used custom checkbox layout in the list view to look different. The designer code for the ListView looks like:

```
        this.listView1.HeaderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeaderStyle.None;
        this.listView1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(104, 90);
        this.listView1.MultiSelect = false;
        this.listView1.Name = "listView1";
        this.listView1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(264, 105);
        this.listView1.Sorting = System.Windows.Forms.SortOrder.Ascending;
        this.listView1.TabIndex = 7;
        this.listView1.UseCompatibleStateImageBehavior = false;
        this.listView1.View = System.Windows.Forms.View.Details;
        this.listView1.MouseClick += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.listView1_MouseClick);
```

Then I declared a list that will hold the selection of the user.

```
    private IList<ListViewItem> m_CheckedItems = new List<ListViewItem>();
```

Here is the initialise method for the ListView. You need to manipulate here for the initial look of your listview.

```
    private void InitialiseListView(IList<string> data)
    {
        listView1.Items.Clear();
        m_CheckedItems.Clear();
        listView1.Columns.Clear();
        listView1.Columns.Add("Col1");
        listView1.Columns[0].Width = listView1.Width;
        ListView.ListViewItemCollection collection = new ListView.ListViewItemCollection(listView1);
        ImageList images = new ImageList();
        images.Images.Add(global::MyApplication.Properties.Resources.Checkbox_Unchecked);
        images.Images.Add(global::MyApplication.Properties.Resources.Checkbox_Checked);
        listView1.SmallImageList = images;
        foreach (string str in data)
        {
            ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
            item.ImageIndex = 0;
            item.Text = str;
            collection.Add(item);
        }
    }
```

This event triggers when the user selects an option in the list view. The selection is recorded in the list I created above and the checked image is displayed so that it looks like the user has selected the item.

```
    private void listView1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left && listView1.FocusedItem != null)
        {
            if (listView1.FocusedItem.ImageIndex == 1)
            {
                listView1.FocusedItem.ImageIndex = 0;
                m_CheckedItems.Remove(listView1.FocusedItem);
            }
            else
            {
                listView1.FocusedItem.ImageIndex = 1;
                m_CheckedItems.Add(listView1.FocusedItem);
            }
        }
    }
```

You can probably fiddle with fonts and forecolor of these items ... Each item within a List View is of type ListViewItem so you can individually manipulate it.

Hope this gives you some direction :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a MyListView: ListView and override `OnDrawSubItem`. Have the `e.Item.Tag` to store the "Clicked" state and update the background according to its state.

```
   public partial class ObjectListView : ListView  {  
(....)    

protected override void OnDrawSubItem(DrawListViewSubItemEventArgs e)
{
      if(bool)e.Item.Tag)
        (...) animate
}
```

Comment: There's an idea but it's not suitable i'm afraid

Answer (score 1):

You can do that easier in WPF.

**WPF Basic**

> 1. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754130.aspx
> 2. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Presentation_Foundation

**WPF Animation**

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752312.aspx

**ListView animation sample**

> 1. [(WPF) Animate ListView item move](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1317367/wpf-animate-listview-item-move)
> 2. [WPF ListView animation by reorder of items?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207376/wpf-listview-animation-by-reorder-of-itens)